# How to open Dialogbox in mvc3 using telerik Extension for asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

i have develop a small mvc3 application using Telerik Extension for asp.net mvc3 in this i want open a dialog box that when i click the link button..Is it possible?if possible please guide me how to done this please help me..

Comment: Have you seen this http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/window?theme=vista

Comment: Hi..i have try this wibndow it is working.But,in this i want add the custom Buttons and text boxes to save the data into database please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have missed [this one](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/window/popupform?theme=vista). They are showing window as popup on button click but you can configure it on any event you want. you just have to write on line in event handler

```
$('#Window').data('tWindow').open();
```

Moreover, example also shows embedding a feedaback form in window

Comment: Hi thank you i am serching for this link thank you so much... i will try this code

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery modal popup window in this case It is inline hidden div you can add controls on it. Demo can be seen [here](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/inline-modal-window-w-css-and-jquery/).